# Can a default parameter be used after being followed by *args?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example if I have:

```
def foo(arg1, def_par="yes", *args,**kwargs):
     print(arg1,def_par)

     for key, value in kwargs.items():
          print("{},{}".format(key,value))

     for arg in args:
         print(arg)

foo("Hello",1,2,smell="funky")
```

Then the interpreter outputs:

```
>>Hello 1
>>smell,funky
>>2
```

Is there a way to create an output where, unless explicitly defined by a keyword argument, the default argument is used to create an output such as:

```
>>Hello Yes
>>smell,funky
>>1
>>2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put variable positional arguments before keyword arguments:

Change:

```
def foo(arg1, def_par="yes", *args,**kwargs):
```

to:

```
def foo(arg1, *args, def_par="yes", **kwargs):
```

With this change, your code would output:

```
Hello yes
smell,funky
1
2
```

If for some reason you can't or don't want to change the function signature of `foo`, you can obtain the default value of a parameter with `inspect.signature`:

```
import inspect
foo("Hello", inspect.signature(foo).parameters['def_par'].default, 1, 2, smell="funky")
```

Comment: I understand this is a way to get the default parameter to be used, but it's not really what I was asking. To clarify, I was asking if using the default parameter is possible using the current function arguements, without having the 2nd argument (in this case the 1) be used. Is there a way to access that default parameter value, without having to explicitly declare it? Like if I could use something similar to self/this like this -> foo("Hello", self.def_par, 1,2,smell="funky")

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with what you ask for then. If you can, however, it's still best that you change the function signature so that you can use the default value of `def_par` more easily.

Comment: Okay makes sense! Thanks for the response!